# Are there any members interested in assisting as an official moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation

A few months ago we lost one of our site moderators. The remaining two moderators are not as active in the community these days. While I will continue to be a moderator on this site (and I'm assuming Nathan will do so as well), I'd like to see if there is any interest from one of our more active members to be a moderator.

Please let me know if this is something you would be interested in pursuing.

Comment: Good initiative - we need more than 2 moderators.

Comment: Sadly this post clearly shows the inactivity of this meta. Which is also kinda symbolic for Ebooks.SE in general.
I try to through the review queues on a regular basis. But I don't see a lot of other people going through them. So often my reviews are probably not even helpful at all as they never conclude with enough supporting reviews.

Comment: I agree... there are only a few of us who seem to look at the review queues on any sort of regular cadence. Unfortunately, we also lost a moderator and the other one has not been on the site since Feb 27th.

Answer (score 4):

You asked for help in March and up until August no one felt chosen to join you as a moderator.

As mentioned in a comment above I'm anyways trying to keep an eye on the Ebooks.SE review queues on a regular basis. And I'd also be willing to help you on other moderation tasks.

But I actually wouldn't have put my name on a ballot. As I really don't have too many contributions to the content of Ebooks.SE. Also my access to review is still rather limited with a mere ~600 reputation.
On the other side, I did contribute with ~400 reviews over the past years.

If you think I can be of help for <s>you</s> the community, feel free to reach out!

Comment: If you're interesting in becoming a moderator (there is no election since the site is still in beta), I can have that arranged.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like we will be given a chance to do an election in the near future!

Comment: As mentioned above, I'll happily offer my support.
I'm a bit unsure how much participation we can expect for an election. But that would surely be the prefered way to go.

Comment: Well the election is a go. I'd encourage you to add yourself to the ballot. Moderation is not focused on how much reputation your have on the topics for this site, but more on the type of tasks in which you already participate.

Comment: Cool thing to see this up now :) I'll consider adding myself during nomination period.

Comment: Awesome Daniel.

Comment: I hope you're still interested Daniel. So far, nobody has added themselves to the nomination for the official election other than myself (tbh, I was hoping there would be enough candidates that I could let some other people take over... 7 years is a long time).

Comment: @JasonDown I did take some days to make up my mind on the whole topic of moderating a SE site.
Surely, nominating myself as a moderator felt like a different magnitude than posting this answer in here.
You can find my nomination now on the election page :)

Comment: Awesome Daniel!